# Ionic cordova restore correct history $state after refresh

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to mobile development but I just started with Cordova. I'd like for my app to also be used as the mobile version of the website so it needs to handle page refreshes correctly.

In particular [this issue here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1647) concerning the fact that the $state history gets wiped clean when you refresh the browser. So if you are on a nested state and you refresh, the back button would disappear and you would literally have no way to get back.

The solution posted in the thread doesn't work, I spent a bunch of time trying to figure it out out to no avail how to get a normal solution to this problem (perhaps even with less lines of code, is the hope).

I feel like this is a common case that should already have a solution somewhere, does anyone have one?